# Pulling numbers in text str from pdf after a character with no white space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python / programming in general.  I'm trying to pull a six digit number following an alpha character in a string like this:

A12345612341234 asdfa we'a aslkfj4353 alsdfasA345678asA858585943

So in the above I would want to pull A123456 and loop to pull A345678 and A858585.  How can I do that?  I'm using PyPDF2 to pull the text from a pdf and set it to a variable, but I've tried splicing and lists, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.  I've spent some time searching the internet and find tons of examples, but they don't relate to my situation, most have whitespace.  Seems like it should be real simple.  This is what I'm working on

```
#import PyPDF2 and set extracted text as the page_content variable
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('5302.pdf','rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()


#initialize the user_input variable
user_input = ""

#function to get the AFE numbers from the pdf document
def get_afenumbers(Y):

    #initialize the afe and afelist variables
    afe = "A"
    afelist = ""
    x = ""

    #Make a while loop of this after figuring out how to get only 6 digits
    #after the "A" use .isdigit() somehow?
    while True:

        if user_input.upper().startswith("Y") == True:

                #Find the letter A and extract it and its following 6 digits
                if "A" in page_content:
                    #right now only getting everything after first A
                    afe = page_content[page_content.find("A")+1:]

                    #Add AFEs to afelist
                    afelist += afe

                    #Build a string of AFEs seperated by a new line character
                    x = x + '\n' + afe
                    print(afe)
                    break

                else:
                    afe = "No AFE numbers found..."

        if user_input.upper().startswith("N") == True:
            print("HAVE A GREAT DAY - GOODBYE!!!")
            break

#Build a while loop for initial question prompt (when Y or N is not True):
while user_input != "Y" and user_input != "N":
    user_input = input('List AFE numbers? Y or N: ').upper()

    if user_input not in ["Y","N"]:
        print('"',user_input,'"','is an invalid input')

get_afenumbers(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to pull out your matches.

Ignoring your loop, we can set the text to search using:

```
text = '''A12345612341234 asdfa we'a aslkfj4353 alsdfasA345678asA858585943'''
```

Now we want to match any capital letter (`[A-Z]`) followed by 6 of any number (`[0-9]{6}`). In your code it looks like you only want `A`, so you could replace the [A-Z] with just A:

```
import re 
re.findall('[A-Z][0-9]{6}', text)
```

which gives your answer:

```
['A123456', 'A345678', 'A858585']
```

Comment: This worked great.  There's a chapter about them in Automate The Boring Stuff With Python that explains some how they work.  Thanks.  I just changed the [A-Z] to [A]